# error Unexpected console statement no-console Jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster, eslint, tslint

I know this question have been asked before, but I cannot get read of the error.
I'm using VS code, node.js and maven. The error occurs when I run npm start and mvn to run my project.

I've tried adding the following on either tslint.json, .eslintrc.json or package.json.

```
"rules": {
    "no-console": false
}
```

I'm a Junior dev, can you guide me through this ? Here is a picture of the root files of my project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add the console.log statement or is it generated? You can ignore the rule in specific files too.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
"no-console": "off"
```